# Как можно переписать некоторые ключи в файле .env проекта используя python?

Tags: python, .env

Делаю проект по автоматизации разворота из коробки проекта по ларавел , пишу скрипт на пайтоне , который скачивает ларавел и необходимые пакеты в зависимости от введёных флагов пользователем . Столкнулся с проблемой , что не могу записать необходимые данные связанные с базой данных в файле .env , используя python load_dotenv пакет

Comment: А зачем какой-то load_dotenv использовать? Записать обычный текстовый файл через обычный open() не вариант?

Comment: Придётся с нуля всё записывать , а так хочется изменить только значение существующего ключа.

Comment: Любое изменение будет перезаписывать файл с нуля, потому что по-другому технически невозможно. Даже найденное вами решение тоже перезаписывает файл с нуля, хоть и скрывает это от вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение

```
pip install -U "python-dotenv[cli]"

subprocess.check_call('dotenv -q never set КЛЮЧ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ')
```